# Django redirect user to shopping cart after item is added

Tags: django, redirect, shopping-cart

In a Django / python website, I have a button that adds the selected item to the shopping cart but I need the user to then be redirected to the cart, but nothing I've tried has worked.  Any help would be appreciated. I'm a novice at this.

The button code:

```
<button                     
    data-product="{{product.id}}"
    data-action="add"
    class="btn button button--primary add-btn update-cart">
    Book this event
</button>
```

Comment: You could write a POST view for the logic to add items to shopping cart and redirect from that view to the shopping part GET view in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**#html**

```
<button                     
    data-product="{{product.id}}"
    data-action="add"
    class="btn button button--primary add-btn update-cart"
    onclick="window.open('{% url 'cartURL' pID=product.id %}')"
    >
    Book this event
</button>
```

**#url.py**

add this url pattern

```
path('cartURL/<str:pID>/', views.cartView, name='cartURL')
```

**#view.py**

```
def cartView(request,pID):
   #add productID and user data in cache,db or session as per your requirement
   return(request,'cart.html',data)
```

Comment: Hello @itsmehemant.  Thank you very much!  It works now.  All I had to do was add onclick="window.open('{% url 'cart'  %}')"> and it worked.  The path and the view were already in place.  I was using the wrong syntax in the button code.  I appreciate your help

Comment: I just notices it opens a new window.  This has confused the owner so I need to make it redirect without opening a new window

Comment: @Michael pass an another argument "target='_self'"  to window.open() to redirect same window https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp or you can use "window.location.href='myurl.com';"

Comment: Thank you for your help.  All working perfectly now!